# What's the best way to exploit a managed metadata column for document keywords?

Tags: search, managed-metadata, information-management, information-architecture, keyword

I have a managed metadata field as a column in a document library. Users have added multiple keywords through this in some cases. What I'd like to do be able to provide a page for browsing the keywords with links to pages showing all items with those keywords added. Is there a way to do this without SharePoint Designer? Do I need to enable search features?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do exactly as you describe.

BUT why not use metadata navigation in the views of the library?

- Go to the library
- In the library tab select "Library settings"
- Select "Metadata navigation settings"
- In the "Configure Navigation Hierarchies" move your managed metadata field to the right
- Click OK

Now in every view of the library you get a picker below the quick launch where you can select keywords to filter the documents by